# custom yii navbar keeps login out

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, yii-booster

i am trying to add a custom bootstrap navbar to my site using yii-booster. But instead of using the yii-booster api to generate a navbar, i just used the basic bootstrap framework way. which visually works fine, but for some reason everytime i try to login, i will show me as loged in, but `Yii::app()->user->name` would be **guest** and when i refresh the site it shows login again.

```
<div style="height: auto;" class="navbar-wrapper">
      <div style="top: 0px;" class="navbar<?php if (!Globals::is_home_page()) echo ' navbar-fixed-top';?>" id="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="brand" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>">mysite.com</a>
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav pull-right">
                        <li><a class="" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/#how">How It Works</a></li>
                        <?php
                        if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
                        {
                           echo '<li><a class="" href="'.Yii::app()->createUrl('/login').'">Login</a></li>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo '<li class="dropdown">
                                   <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:void(0);">Profile <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                      <li><a href="'.Yii::app()->createUrl('user').'">Profile</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="'.Yii::app()->createUrl('/orders').'">Schedule</a></li>
                                      <li class="divider"></li>
                                      <li><a href="'.Yii::app()->user->logout().'">Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->isGuest.'   '.Yii::app()->user->id.'  '.Yii::app()->user->name.')</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                  </li>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

but when i use the yii-booster below, it works fine... I don't quite see why we have to use the yii-booster way. coz the bootsrtap api is so much easier. I'm pretty new at this, is there something i'm missing or not understanding here? Thanks in advance...

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="brand" href="#"><?php echo Yii::app()->name ?></a>
            <div class="nav-collapse">
                <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
                    'htmlOptions' => array( 'class' => 'nav' ),
                    'activeCssClass'    => 'active',
                    'items'=>array(
                        array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
                        array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                        array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
                    ),
                )); ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yii::app()->user->name return the username of the user who is logged in.

For testing user is guest

You have to use

```
Yii::app()->user->isGuest;
```

This will give you better result

Comment: i am using `if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest) { }` it logs out after refresh

Comment: try this 
if ( ! Yii::app()->user->id ) { }